# android setMargins

Tags: android, padding, margins

I'm developing some kinda stopwatch app, very similar to the default one, I'm doing that just to make sure I have the basic knowledge. My problem: after pressing the Lap button a new layout is created and the current value of tvDisplay (textview showing the timer) is placed in a new textview (see the code below). It works, but I want to separate the dynamically added layouts from each other to make the whole thing look better. I tried to set the padding for nlap LinearLayout but it didn't work. I also didn't find a setMargins() method.. What can I do to add some dp of free space between dynamically added Linear Layouts?

XML:

```
<ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/LapHost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

             <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

                 </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

java:

```
    public void LapClick(View view) {

    LinearLayout lap = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lap);
    TextView disp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    TextView ms = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerMs);

    ScrollView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(
            ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout nlap = new LinearLayout(this);
    nlap.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    nlap.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    nlap.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C7C7C7"));

    TextView value = new TextView(this);
    value.setText(disp.getText().toString() + ms.getText().toString());
    value.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A60101"));
                value.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    nlap.addView(value);
    lap.addView(nlap);

}
```

Comment: why is your layoutParam a ScrollView.LayoutParam if you are not putting the view in a ScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0); // 10 px from top
```

Comment: Use LinearLayout.LayoutParams and NOT ScrollView.LayoutParams since we are dealing with a LinearLayout here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the margin by the `LayoutParams` :

```
layoutParams.topMargin = 25;
```